# Consulta PHP repetindo o medicamento

Tags: php

Para explicar o meu caso, preciso primeiro explicar como funciona uma dispensação de medicamentos da Farmácia Popular (o programa do Governo Federal).

Estou fazendo um sistema para melhor organização da dispensação aqui na minha farmácia.

**Como funciona a dispensação?**

1) O paciente chega na farmácia portando a receita, documento com foto e CPF.

2) Se a receita estiver dentro da validade (ela é válida por 180 dias da data da consulta), dispensamos os medicamentos para a dose equivalente a 30 dias.

3) A dispensação é feita normalmente e salva no BD.

*Obs:*

- Um paciente pode ter X receitas válidas;
- Uma receita pode haver Y medicamentos;

---

Pois bem, o sistema estava funcionando bem, quando me dei conta que estava atualizando a dispensação, quando a mesma precisa ficar cadastrada (para uma consulta posterior).
O sistema exibe todas as receitas do paciente normalmente, usando a seguinte consulta:

*Consulta PHP completa que exibe todas as receitas por paciente:*

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT a.crm, a.data_receita, a.data_dispensacao, a.receita, a.id_paciente, b.classe, a.id AS id_disp, GROUP_CONCAT(b.medicamento SEPARATOR '|||') medicamentos, GROUP_CONCAT(a.quantidade SEPARATOR '|||') quantidades FROM dispensacao a INNER JOIN medicamentos b ON b.id  = a.id_medicamento WHERE a.id_paciente = {$ln['id']} GROUP BY data_receita";
 $query1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);

 while($lnReceita = $query1->fetch_array()){

echo '
      <div id="'.$lnReceita['id_disp'].'" class="card receita-dispensada card-receitas-'.$lnReceita['id_disp'].'">
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="card-content-inner">
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">today</i> <b>Data da Receita</b></div>
              <div class="col-50"><a href="#" class="data-receita">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($lnReceita['data_receita'])).'</a> <span class="apagar_receita" style="left: 90%; position: absolute"><a href="#">Apagar</a></span> </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">today_fill</i> <b>Data da Dispensação</b></div>
              <div class="col-50"><a href="#" data-receita="'.$lnReceita['data_receita'].'" data-classe="'.$lnReceita['classe'].'" data-crm="'.$lnReceita['crm'].'" data-idpac="'.$lnReceita['id_paciente'].'" class="data-dispensacao">'.date('d/m/Y', strtotime($lnReceita['data_dispensacao'])).'</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">card</i> <b>CRM</b></div>
              <div class="col-50">'.$lnReceita['crm'].'</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
              <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">list</i> <b>Medicamentos Dispensados</b></div>
                <div class="col-50">
                  <div class="data-table card centralized">
                    <table>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th class="label-cell">Medicamento</th>
                          <th class="numeric-cell">Quantidade</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="list_med">
';

$medicamentos = explode('|||', $lnReceita['medicamentos']);
$quantidades = explode('|||', $lnReceita['quantidades']);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($medicamentos); $i++) {
  echo '
    <tr>
      <td class="label-cell">'.$medicamentos[$i].'</td>
      <td class="numeric-cell">'.$quantidades[$i].'</td>
    </tr>';
}

echo '
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row receita" style="margin-bottom: 15px">
                <div class="col-50"><i class="icon f7-icons size-16">images</i> <b>Receita</b></div>
                <div class="col-50"><img id="img_receita_'.$lnReceita['id_disp'].'" src="'.PATH_IMGS.''.$lnReceita['receita'].'" width="100" height="100"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-50"></div>
                <div class="col-50 theme-orange">
                  <a href="#" class="button button-fill acoes_print" style="margin-top: -5px"><i class="material-icons color-white icon_btn">print</i><span class="label_btn"> Imprimir</span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>                         
';
  }

 echo '  </div>
        <div class="row">
          <a style="padding-bottom: 15px; height: 30px" href="#" class="col-100 button button-fill add_receita"><i class="icon f7-icons size-12 color-white">add_round</i> Adicionar Receita</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>';
 }
```

**O ERRO:**

A cada dispensação, é acrescentado ao BD, e a única coisa que muda de um paciente, é a data_dispensacao, que, na consulta acima, REPETE o medicamento.

[image: Exibindo o medicamento duplicado]

**Estrutura do BD:**

```
    -- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `dispensacao`
--

CREATE TABLE `dispensacao` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_paciente` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_medicamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantidade` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `crm` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data_receita` date NOT NULL,
  `data_dispensacao` date NOT NULL,
  `receita` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `medicamentos`
--

CREATE TABLE `medicamentos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `medicamento` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `laboratorio` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `classe` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `pacientes`
--

CREATE TABLE `pacientes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `documento` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `procuracao` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `senha` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Índices de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- Índices de tabela `dispensacao`
--
ALTER TABLE `dispensacao`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Índices de tabela `medicamentos`
--
ALTER TABLE `medicamentos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Índices de tabela `pacientes`
--
ALTER TABLE `pacientes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Índices de tabela `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `dispensacao`
--
ALTER TABLE `dispensacao`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=284;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `medicamentos`
--
ALTER TABLE `medicamentos`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=25;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `pacientes`
--
ALTER TABLE `pacientes`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=116;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

**O que espero:**

Que apenas não repita o medicamento, a cada nova dispensação do mesma receita para o paciente!

Desde já agradeço!

Comment: O `GROUP BY` deveria ser no código do medicamento e não na data da receita, não?

Comment: Eu tentei isso também, mas quando o paciente tem 2 receitas, só exibe uma. =/

Comment: Tenta colocar, antes de fechar o loop, uma variável com o código que está repetindo, e no início um IF comparando se essa variável for diferente do código carregado no final. Algo assim: `for(...){ if(codigo_receita != código_vindo_do_banco){ exibe a receita }; codigo_receita=código_vindo_do_banco;}`

Comment: Se puder postar na pergunta o código do loop que tá puxando os dados do banco seria mais fácil de exemplificar.

Comment: Ok, irei tentar mais tarde @DavidSamm Obrigado!

Comment: @DavidSamm editei com a consulta completa!

Comment: Tenta colocar `array_unique()` em `$medicamentos`, ficando assim: `$medicamentos = array_unique(explode('|||', $lnReceita['medicamentos']));`. Isso elimina itens repetidos na array.

Comment: @DavidSamm funcionou! Poderia postar a resposta e uma breve explicação? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O SQL está retornando os medicamentos em duplicidade. Uma forma simples de resolver isso sem mexer no SQL é eliminar duplicidade na Array `$medicamentos` com a função `array_unique()`:

```
$medicamentos = array_unique(explode('|||', $lnReceita['medicamentos']));
```

**Referência:** https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use o [`DISTINCT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html) para não retornar itens repetidos. Veja:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.crm, a.data_receita, a.data_dispensacao ...
```

Comment: Sim, eu tentei mas ainda repete.

Comment: @GuilhermeLirio e se você colocar um COUNT(DISTINCT b.medicamento) por exemplo. Tenta ai.

Comment: Ah não, mas neste caso talvez teria que agrupar por nome do medicamente também. Estou pensando aqui um pouco. Seria interessante você deixar na sua pergunta os scripts (não a imagem dos scripts) para criação desta tabela. ISso facilita a reprodução para quem tentar te ajudar.

Comment: Humm, tudo bem, irei upá-lo aqui (apenar que não sei como fazer isso direito kkkk).

Comment: Ali na Estrutura do BD, em vez de colocar a imagem, coloque o CREATE TABLE ... bla bla bla... porque assim facilita para as pessoas que estão respondendo, ou tentando responder =D

Comment: Pronto! @acklay